# New Apollo Error Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: status code 400

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, prisma

I am working with graphql/apollo and Prisma Cloud server and have been attempting to link to my new react client for adding players to a team in a club. I am however getting a 400 status code error. I have been looking through many other similar errors and attempted to replicate and resolve but can't seem to figure this one out.

Here is my app.js

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';


//components
import TeamList from './components/TeamList'
import PlayerList from './components/PlayerList';
import AddPlayer from './components/AddPlayer';
import AddTeam from './components/AddTeam';


//apollo client setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <div id="main">
      <h1>Coach Ed</h1>
     <TeamList/>
     <PlayerList/>
     <AddPlayer/>
     <AddTeam/>
     </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Add Player component:

```
class AddPlayer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            playername: "",
            team: ""
        };
    }
        displayTeams(){
            var data = this.props.getTeamsQuery;
            if(data.loading){
                return( <option disabled>Loading teams</option> );
            } else {
                return data.teams.map(team => {
                    return( <option key={ team.id } value={team.id}>{ team.title }</option> );
                });
            }
        }
```

Here is my add player mutation

```
const addPlayerMutation = gql`
    mutation{
        createPlayer(playername: "", teamId: ""){
            playername
            id
        }
    }
`;

export { getPlayersQuery, getTeamsQuery, addPlayerMutation}
```

Here is the schema information from server

```
type Mutation {
     createPlayer(data: CreatePlayerInput!): Player!
  }

type Player {
    id: ID!
    playername: String!
    coachcreator: User!
    team: Team!
    updatedAt: String!
    createdAt: String!
}

input CreatePlayerInput {
    playername: String!
    team: ID!
}
```

Here is my Create Player Mutation on Server

```
async createPlayer(parent, args, { prisma, request }, info) {
        const userId = getUserId(request)
        const teamExists = await prisma.exists.Team({
            id: args.data.team,
            published: true
        })

        if (!teamExists) {
            throw new Error('Unable to find team')
        }

        return prisma.mutation.createPlayer({
            data: {
                playername: args.data.playername,
                coachcreator: {
                    connect: {
                        id: userId
                    }
                },
                team: {
                    connect: {
                        id: args.data.team
                    }
                }
            }
        }, info)
    },
```

This is the error that I am receiving

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

and

````
POST http://localhost:4000/ 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:7153
Subscription    @   0.chunk.js:72989
subscribe   @   0.chunk.js:73067
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:6788
Subscription    @   0.chunk.js:72989
subscribe   @   0.chunk.js:73067
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:5126
Subscription    @   0.chunk.js:72989
subscribe   @   0.chunk.js:73067
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:5321
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:5316
step    @   0.chunk.js:71481
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:71412
(anonymous) @   0.chunk.js:71385
__awaiter   @   0.chunk.js:71364
QueryManager.mutate @   0.chunk.js:5256
ApolloClient.mutate @   0.chunk.js:6626
MutationData.mutate @   0.chunk.js:1303
MutationData._this.runMutation  @   0.chunk.js:1254
submitForm  @   main.chunk.js:175
callCallback    @   0.chunk.js:40512
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   0.chunk.js:40561
invokeGuardedCallback   @   0.chunk.js:40614
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   0.chunk.js:40629
executeDispatch @   0.chunk.js:40714
executeDispatchesInOrder    @   0.chunk.js:40739
executeDispatchesAndRelease @   0.chunk.js:43623
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @   0.chunk.js:43632
forEachAccumulated  @   0.chunk.js:43604
runEventsInBatch    @   0.chunk.js:43649```
````

plus also

```
ncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (0.chunk.js:4119)
    at Object.error (0.chunk.js:5357)
    at notifySubscription (0.chunk.js:72934)
    at onNotify (0.chunk.js:72973)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (0.chunk.js:73030)
    at 0.chunk.js:5134
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (0.chunk.js:5133)
    at notifySubscription (0.chunk.js:72934)
    at onNotify (0.chunk.js:72973)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (0.chunk.js:73030)
    at Object.error (0.chunk.js:6827)
    at notifySubscription (0.chunk.js:72934)
    at onNotify (0.chunk.js:72973)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (0.chunk.js:73030)
    at 0.chunk.js:7169
```

I have read up on adding 'cors' but almost all are linked to working with Express and not sure if same principles apply. Also been some discussion on installing Apollo Error Handling and couldn't quite figure out how to implement this with import and versions between Apollo versions being an issue.

Any help with the error shown above would be much appreciated.

Comment: bad mutation - read docs about passing query variables

Comment: @xadm thanks for the feedback, will look into the docs as suggested. Could you be more specific with where the obvious errors are here? I think it is do with the addPlayerMutation passing values, but not exactly sure. First attempt at connecting client to server here. Thanks.

Comment: problem is about passing values [and related to this query/mutation syntax] - read docs again or search for tutorial